# How to toggle class name with ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I want that each click on `.clickClass` would affect toggle `.foo` on `.present` class -

mean -

init - `present` ,

1st click `present foo`

2nd click `present`

and so on ...

so far I have -

```
<div class="clickClass" ng-click="className= 'foo'"></div>
<div class="present {{className}}"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/urielz/qQdn7/1/

How to get that  ?

Update  :

Here is sample works - http://plnkr.co/edit/0lu6x8uP7nVcTTYaNj4o?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="clickClass" ng-click="classToggle = !classToggle"></div>
<div class="present" ng-class="{'foo': classToggle}"></div>
```

See the docs on [`ng-class`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.19/docs/api/ng/directive/ngClass) for more info.